# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Tags: sql-server, iis, vbscript

I have website which is working on my one server now I have migrated to another server changed the connection string. But one weird thing is some pages working fine but some page show me " page can not be displayed error message. I am new in VBscript Can anyone help me what am missing"

Below is the code of page which is not working on new server but working on old server

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' : object required

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<% if session("MM_Username") = "" or isnull(session("MM_Username")) then
    response.redirect("/login.asp")
   end if

 %>

<%


Dim MM_editAction
Dim MM_abortEdit
Dim MM_editQuery
Dim MM_editCmd

Dim MM_editConnection
Dim MM_editTable
Dim MM_editRedirectUrl
Dim MM_editColumn
Dim MM_recordId

Dim MM_fieldsStr
Dim MM_columnsStr
Dim MM_fields
Dim MM_columns
Dim MM_typeArray
Dim MM_formVal
Dim MM_delim
Dim MM_altVal
Dim MM_emptyVal
Dim MM_i

MM_editAction = CStr(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
If (Request.QueryString <> "") Then
  MM_editAction = MM_editAction & "?" & Server.HTMLEncode(Request.QueryString)
End If

' boolean to abort record edit
MM_abortEdit = false

' query string to execute
MM_editQuery = ""
%>
<%
' *** Update Record: set variables

If (CStr(Request("MM_update")) = "form1" And CStr(Request("MM_recordId")) <> "") Then

  MM_editConnection = MM_v3_STRING
  MM_editTable = "dbo.custMessage"
  MM_editColumn = "id"
  MM_recordId = "" + Request.Form("MM_recordId") + ""
  MM_editRedirectUrl = "Change.asp"
  MM_fieldsStr  = "textarea|value"
  MM_columnsStr = "message|',none,''"

  ' create the MM_fields and MM_columns arrays
  MM_fields = Split(MM_fieldsStr, "|")
  MM_columns = Split(MM_columnsStr, "|")

  ' set the form values
  For MM_i = LBound(MM_fields) To UBound(MM_fields) Step 2
    MM_fields(MM_i+1) = CStr(Request.Form(MM_fields(MM_i)))
  Next

  ' append the query string to the redirect URL
  If (MM_editRedirectUrl <> "" And Request.QueryString <> "") Then
    If (InStr(1, MM_editRedirectUrl, "?", vbTextCompare) = 0 And Request.QueryString <> "") Then
      MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "?" & Request.QueryString
    Else
      MM_editRedirectUrl = MM_editRedirectUrl & "&" & Request.QueryString
    End If
  End If

End If
%>
<%
' *** Update Record: construct a sql update statement and execute it

If (CStr(Request("MM_update")) <> "" And CStr(Request("MM_recordId")) <> "") Then

  ' create the sql update statement
  MM_editQuery = "update " & MM_editTable & " set "
  For MM_i = LBound(MM_fields) To UBound(MM_fields) Step 2
    MM_formVal = MM_fields(MM_i+1)
    MM_typeArray = Split(MM_columns(MM_i+1),",")
    MM_delim = MM_typeArray(0)
    If (MM_delim = "none") Then MM_delim = ""
    MM_altVal = MM_typeArray(1)
    If (MM_altVal = "none") Then MM_altVal = ""
    MM_emptyVal = MM_typeArray(2)
    If (MM_emptyVal = "none") Then MM_emptyVal = ""
    If (MM_formVal = "") Then
      MM_formVal = MM_emptyVal
    Else
      If (MM_altVal <> "") Then
        MM_formVal = MM_altVal
      ElseIf (MM_delim = "'") Then  ' escape quotes
        MM_formVal = "'" & Replace(MM_formVal,"'","''") & "'"
      Else
        MM_formVal = MM_delim + MM_formVal + MM_delim
      End If
    End If
    If (MM_i <> LBound(MM_fields)) Then
      MM_editQuery = MM_editQuery & ","
    End If
    MM_editQuery = MM_editQuery & MM_columns(MM_i) & " = " & MM_formVal
  Next
  MM_editQuery = MM_editQuery & " where " & MM_editColumn & " = " & MM_recordId

  If (Not MM_abortEdit) Then
    ' execute the update
    Set MM_editCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection = MM_editConnection
    MM_editCmd.CommandText = MM_editQuery
    MM_editCmd.Execute
    MM_editCmd.ActiveConnection.Close

    If (MM_editRedirectUrl <> "") Then
      Response.Redirect(MM_editRedirectUrl)
    End If
  End If

End If
%>
<%
Dim change__MMColParam
change__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request("MM_EmptyValue") <> "") Then 
  change__MMColParam = Request("MM_EmptyValue")
End If
%>
<%
Dim change
Dim change_numRows

Set change = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
change.ActiveConnection = MM_v3_STRING
change.Source = "SELECT * FROM dbo.custMessage WHERE id = " + Replace(change__MMColParam, "'", "''") + ""
change.CursorType = 0
change.CursorLocation = 2
change.LockType = 1
change.Open()

change_numRows = 0
%>
<%

'setup database connection
    dim conn
    set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;User ID=***;Password=***;Initial Catalog=heart_Test;Data Source=****;"
    conn.Open

%>
```

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is a classic example of sql injection gone wild. My friend Bobby Tables loves this type of code. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Meanwhile wanna-be haxor script kiddies are wringing their hands in pleasure whilst looking at their next Sql-Injection victim....

Comment: @SeanLange But this same code working perfectly on another server

Comment: You are obviously missing the point. The error is a by-product of writing your queries the wrong way. For the question at hand, you are going to have to debug this. And debugging classic asp is a real pain. You will have to add response.write lines all over the place so you have an idea of where the issue is happening. Once you get get that isolated you should be to fine tune the debugging to provide you some insight.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer.
Start Internet Services Manager.
Click Default Web Site, and then click Properties. 
Double-click ASP in the Features pane. 
Expand Behavior. 
Click Enable Parent Paths. 
Click True for Enable Parent Paths. 
Click Apply.